# Use content-disposition with Axios and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

Hi guys I'm using `nodejs` and trying the API from https://www.lalal.ai/api/help/

```
$ curl --url https://www.lalal.ai/api/upload/ --data-binary @any_file.mp3 --header "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=any_file.mp3" --header "Authorization: license 14abcde0"
```

This is my code

```
app.post("/uploads", upload.any("tmparr"), async (req, res, next) => {
  const ucuk = req.files[0];
  // console.log(ucuk);

  Axios.post("https://www.lalal.ai/api/upload/", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=${ucuk.path}`,
      Authorization: "license ec2a55f4",
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
})
```

And I got this error

```
(node:31608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 405
    at createError (D:\reactjs\crud-mern\server\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\reactjs\crud-mern\server\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
```

Can someone explain to me why that is error and how to fix it ? :D

Comment: You can start by adding a `.catch()` after the `.then()` so you can catch the promise rejection.

Answer (score 0):

`axios.post` takes **three** arguments:

1. The URL
2. The data you are posting
3. The config

You've missed out number 2.

You also seem to be passing the full path in the `content-disposition` header instead of just the file name.

Comment: can you give me an example?